# Using nohup with builtin unix commands with params and file redirection

Tags: bash, nohup

I would like to run this command:

```
tail -f mylog.log > snippet.log
```

I want to run it in the background and not worry about shell timing out or other problems.

This throws warnings and errors:

```
nohup tail -f mylog.log > snippet.log & > nohup2.out (or dev null)
```

What would be the proper command?

Comment: Might be helpful to see those errors and warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not make sense.

If you want to redirect the stdin and stderr channels, then you will use this:

```
nohup tail -f mylog.log > ./messages.log 2> ./errors.out
```

If you want all messages to go into one file, you'd use:

```
nohup tail -f mylog.log > all_messages.txt 2>&1
```

If you want to duplicate the messages, you'd use:

```
nohup tail -f mylog.log | tee messages1 messages2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get any messages from nohup itself into nohup2.out, but the & async ends the whole command, and the final redirect would just empty the file.

This seems to work. I closed the originating shell, then tried kill -HUP and kill -INT, both of which it survived.

```
nohup >nohup2.out 2>&1 bash -c 'tail -f mylog.log > snippet.log' &
```